# Cannot connect to Ad-Hoc Wifi

Tags: networking, wifi, dhcp, static-ip

I am attempting to set up a Ad-Hoc Wifi network of multiple PIs , none of them are supposed to be connected to the Internet. I could configure one of the PIs to act as a Ad Hoc Wifi device which provides the Wifi access point with an SSID and a static IP address.

I configured the /etc/interfaces file with the following text:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
wireless-channel 1
wireless-essid CTWifi
wireless-mode ad-hoc
```

I can see the Wifi connection on another raspberry Pi through the Wifi connection GUI

I set up a static IP address (with the same subnet as the ad-hoc Pi) on the other raspberry pi by adding a line to the dhcpcd.conf file so I can connect to the ad-hoc Pi:

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.1.2
```

However, I cannot seem to connect to CTWifi by clicking on it even though it is showing up in the GUI. I tried to change the wpa_supplicant.conf file but that does not work either.

I also tried to set up a DHCP server on the ad-hoc Pi following this guide: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/04/22/raspberry-pi-wireless-communication/

I added the following lines to the dhcpd.conf file on the ad-hoc Pi:

```
ddns-update-style interim;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
authoritative;
log-facility local7;
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.254;
}
```

It still does not work. I cannot seem to connect to the ad-hoc network through the Wifi GUI.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

[image: Can see CT Wifi but cannot connect to it by clicking on it]

Comment: You do not seem to understand ad-hoc ALL devices need to be ad-hoc

Comment: Thanks. Now it works. I think my misunderstanding was that I did not understand that ad hoc means a routerless connection.

Comment: Please make an answer for your solution and accept it after two days. Only accepting an answer will finish a question. Otherwise it will pop up again and again for years (and for nothing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up the ad hoc settings in the other Pi with a static IP address and was able to able to connect to the network